# iOS Accessing views data from delegate without allocating a new view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates, uilocalnotification

I need to change a data (a label) from the app's delegate method `ApplicationDidEnterForeground` without allocating a new view. The view is called "Reminder", so I imported it into the delegate and I can access its data only if I allocate it (Reminder *anything = [Reminder alloc...etc), but since I want to change the current view loaded I need to have direct access to the view that's already loaded.

How would I do to change the main view's label from the delegate as soon as my application enters foreground?

obs: I know I can do it on `-(void)ViewDidLoad` or `-(void)ViewWillAppear` but it won't solve my problem, since it won't change the label if, for example, the user opens the app through a notification box (slide icon when phone is locked). In that case, none of the above methods are called if the app was open in background.

I don't know if I was clear, hope I was. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using storyboards, you can do this to access the current view being seen

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
UINavigationController *a=_window.rootViewController;
Reminder *rem = a.topViewController;
rem.label.text=@"test";
}
```

IF not using story boards

When I create views that I need to access later, I define them as a property, like this

on AppDelegate.h

```
//@interface SIMCAppDelegate : UIResponder <..........>
//{
//Some variables here
//}

//Properties here
@property (strong, nonatomic) Reminder *reminder;

//Some method declaration here
//eg: -(void) showSomething;
```

on AppDelegate.m

```
//@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize reminder;
```

so when I alloc/init the view like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//codes before here

self.reminder = [[Reminder alloc] init];
self.reminder.label.text = @"OLD LABEL";
//codes after here
}
```

I will be able to access it again after allocation on other methods, like this

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

self.reminder.label.text = @"NEW LABEL";
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had already tested with something like this, but I did it again just in case, and followed everything exactly as you written. Still, the label is not changing. Any other guess?

Comment: Actually, the label is not even showing "Old label". It just stays blank. And yes, I've connected everything in storyboard and I can change the label from inside the Reminder.m... I just can't change it outside of it.

Comment: when you set a break point at applicationWillEnterForeground, does it break there? by the way applicationWillEnterForeground != ApplicationDidEnterForeground which is stated in your question

Comment: how do you change the label from inside reminder.m? what is the code/method you called to change it, so i'll have more idea

Comment: For testing purposes, i just changed the label from reminders.m  viewDidLoad method. label.text = @"anything". I've erased that already to prevent conflict with the delegate methods. Is there a way to do things in real time? Like, without depending on delegate standard methods? For example, if a notification arrives, change the label at the same time, not depending exclusively on the application state?

Comment: yes you can change labels on real time. @Abhishek answer is an example of that http://stackoverflow.com/a/11258229/1138331 ... but before that, we must first solve your current problem of changing the label

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13212/discussion-between-heavyprogrammer-and-lucas-vallim-da-costa)

Answer (score 1):

just send a notification from your ApplicationDidEnterForeground: method and receive it on that class where you want to update the label... Like this..

```
//Your ApplicationDidEnterForeground:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationWithName:@"UpdateLabel" withObject:nill];
```

and add observer in it viewDidLoad: of that controller where you want to update label

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                  selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
                                  name:@"UpdateLabel"
                                  object:nil];
```

made your method in same class ...

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification *)notification{
    update label
}
```

Comment: This works great! I don't know why nobody upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can try following code -

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray =  [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i< [activeControllerArray count]; i++) {
    if ([[activeControllerArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[Reminder Class]) {
        Reminder *object = [activeControllerArray objectAtIndex:i];

        //Perform all the task here which you want.

        break; //Once found break the loop to do further processing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rishi. Just one problem, Xcode won't recognize "self.navigationController". Is there some other thing I should do?

Comment: you app delegate contains property of navigation controller?

Comment: I created one now. There were no issues in the Xcode, but when I put a break point in your code, the application is skipping the if statement.

Comment: you can try logging and check whether any view controller is present there or not, might be there is an issue with the navigation hierarchy.

Comment: creating a navigationController is not enough. For this code to work, the navigation controller must be the root controller of your window and all other controllers must be added through it.